# stored procedure returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This stored procedure doesn't work. It just returns 0 rows. I've checked the SQL and it returns the correct value when parsed directly to the DB. What could be wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSaltOfUser
(
    @eMail nvarchar
)
 
AS
DECLARE @result nvarchar
 /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
BEGIN
   SELECT @result = salt
   FROM UserSet
   WHERE eMail = @eMail
   RETURN @result
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 @eMail nvarchar
```

Will truncate the passed in email to one character. You need to put in a length. e.g.

```
  @eMail nvarchar(50)
```

This should match the datatype of the relevant column in `UserSet`

Also do you really want to be using the return code for this or do you want to use an `output parameter` perhaps - or just a scalar select?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSaltOfUser

    (
    @eMail nvarchar (50),      /*Should match datatype of UserSet.eMail*/
    @salt nvarchar (50) OUTPUT /*Should match datatype of UserSet.salt*/
  )

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @result = salt
    FROM UserSet
    WHERE eMail = @eMail
END
```

And to call it

```
DECLARE @salt nvarchar(50)
EXECUTE dbo.GetSaltOfUser N'abc@example.com', @salt OUTPUT
SELECT @salt
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to assign the `salt` to a variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSaltOfUser
(
    @eMail nvarchar    
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT salt
    FROM UserSet
    WHERE eMail = @eMail
END
```

Comment: As it seems, I CAN'T return a var since it has to be an integer? Does this only apply to the "RETURN" command?

Comment: It will return `salt` in whatever datatype it is. You could cast that as anything that you want, with in scope obviously. `CAST(salt AS nvarchar(50)) AS salt`

Answer (score 1):

Two Cents from my end

- Good you are using SET NOCOUNT ON
- Always use RETURN to return status code, Example 0- success, 1 - failure
- Use SELECT to return the ROWS
- Use Try Catch to handle Error Conditions